# I get an error 800a9cf1 while adding a listview control to a userform

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit, userform

I have several userforms that use ListView Control, but it doesn't load in some of our pcs with Windows 10 / Office 10.
I found out that the reference Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) was missing and then I learned how to register it using regsvr32.
Now that i have the reference correctly registered, I can see the listview control in the adittional controls list, and was able to activate it, but when I try to add the control to a form, the error in the Picture below shows up...
Does anyone know whats going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a)` PC's with 32 bit Windows will run into issues with distributed files saved in 64 bit windows as the libraries are registered in different folders (System32 vs SysWOW64).
You could try to goto Excel, delete the library reference on a 32-bit-Office pc manually, re-enter a renewed ListView reference and re-save the project locally. 
`b)` Furthermore the Treeview control represents no native MSForms control and cannot be used at all, if Office is installed as 64 bit version. 
There exist professional solutions, such as a [MSForms (all VBA) treeview](https://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp) *(offering even a free code demo in a simplified version)*.

Comment: I'll try out the ListGrid from the link you provided. thanks for the info.

Comment: I noticed this:
my PC has Win10 + Office16 both 64bit. When I check for the used references of my project, Ms Win Common Controls location shows up as in System32 as show in this image https://ibb.co/gPNVD46 and its Working fine...
Now on another computer with a different office version, 10 also 64bit, I tried to register it on System32 without sucess, but I was able to register it on SysWOW64...and the Reference for Ms Win Common Controls Shows up on the list but I can't activate the control, it gives the error I previously posted...

Comment: Note that even Office versions allowing 64-bit, are frequently *installed* as *32bit version*. SysWOW64 stands for *System Windows(32-bit) on Windows(64-bit)*. 32-bit program trying to install their 32-bit lib files into `C:\Windows\System32`, will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. If the other pc's Office actually is installed as 64 bit version, AFAIK there's no chance - cf. lit b) in answer - @DelmarSilva